# using col b as result I'm guessing self join?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

This seems like it should be so easy. Consider having this table..

```
| parent  | child  |
| aaaa    | bbbb   |
| aaaa    | cccc   |
| aaaa    | dddd   |
| bbbb    | gggg   |
| bbbb    | hhhh   |
| bbbb    | eeee   |
| nnnn    | kkkk   |
| nnnn    | kkkk   |
| cccc    | rrrr   |
| cccc    | tttt   |
| cccc    | wwww   |
| cccc    | xxxx   |
| hhhh    | zzzz   |
| hhhh    | pppp   |
| eeee    | FFFF   |
```

How can I get the child, and then using the child result get all of the children of them and then using that result get those children and so on.. until there are no more matches.

If I select where parent = aaaa my result should be

```
bbbb
 gggg
 hhhh
  zzzz
  pppp
 eeee
  FFFF
cccc
 rrrr
 tttt
 wwww
 xxxx
dddd
```

Comment: You can't. MySQL doesn't support recursion. Choices include joining the table to itself as often as could be required, constructing a sproc, handling the logic in application code, or switching to an alternative model - e.g. Nested sets.

Comment: in Oracle this is done with CONNECT_BY - you might search on that topic also.

Comment: This is sometimes called a hierarchical query. There are some other questions about this on SO, with answers that can only be called grim hacks. But they work. You might look them up.

Comment: `select children.child as leaves from table t 
left join table children ON children.child = t.child 
where t.parent IN (select children.child as leaves 
     from table t 
     left join table children ON children.child = t.child 
     where t.parent = "aaaa");`

Comment: What does that comment mean? If it's an answer, please post it as one (with explanation) and accept it.